# jquery post behaviour help

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

It's meant to call a Action Method called Logon.
depending on the logic i want it to either redirect to a url, or set some error text.

its getting the right information as json data, but all its doing is displaying the json result in a new tab when i click the submit button.

what is wrong here?

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
                $.post({
                    url: "Account/LogOn",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.redirect) {
                            // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
                            window.location.href = data.redirect;
                        }
                        else {
                            // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
                            $("#error").replaceWith(data.error);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Please post your entire stack from controller to viewmodel to entire html page.  Seems like you keep having the same issue again and again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cancel the default action ...

`return false;` at the end of the `click` handler.

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
                $.post({
                    url: "Account/LogOn",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.redirect) {
                            // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
                            window.location.href = data.redirect;
                        }
                        else {
                            // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
                            $("#error").replaceWith(data.error);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
});
```

Comment: hmm, that didnt work for me :(. same outcome, produces {"redirect":"/Home/Index"} in another browser tab

Comment: also not sure if this affects things, but the form with the submit button is within a jquery ui modal dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you doing this on client side and not the server side?

On Server side you can redirect or redisplay the logon form with errors.

```
 return Redirect(returnUrl);
return View(model); //model contains the Model Errors. It can be added using ModelState.AddModelError(...);
```

Comment: If he's doing this as part of an AJAX request, only the AJAX request will be redirected, and there aren't any really easy ways to tell in your handling code whether this happened.